# Lagrange multipliers and critical points

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I have (probably) a fundamental problem understanding something related critical points and Lagrange multipliers.

As we know, if a function assumes an extreme value in an interior point of some open set, then the gradient of the function is 0.

Now, when dealing with constraint optimization using Lagrange multipliers, we also find an extreme value of the function restricted to some curve.

So why in the case of constraint optimization can't we also search for points where the gradient is 0? What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the gradient along the constraint can be zero even though the gradient itself isn't. For instance, in $\Bbb R^3$, take the function $f(x,y,z)=z$, and constrain it to the unit sphere. The gradient of $f$ is non-zero everywhere.

However, imagine you lived on the sphere and had no idea that is part of a bigger space. In other words, like we do on earth if we forget that we can fly up or dig down. Then we would think that the gradient of the function $f$ was zero on the north and south poles, simply because in any direction we can conceive, $f$ if stationary at those two points. *Those* are the kind of points Lagrange multipliers let us find.

If course, if the true gradient happens to be zero on the constraint, then of course it's also zero along the constraint. However, that's only a small special case among all cases where the gradient along the surface is zero, and using the method of Lagrange multipliers we pick up those automatically along with all the others.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "the gradient along the constraint"?

Comment: @Mr.Tea The constraint gives us a so-called "hypersurface", i.e. a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ with dimension $n-1$. At each point on the hypersurface, the gradient of $f$ can be decomposed into one component which is perpendicular to the hypersurface, and one which is parallel to the surface. What I mean by "gradient along the constraint" is simply that parallel component. This is also the idea behind Lagrange multipliers: it tells you when the gradient of $f$ is completely perpendicular to the hypersurface, which means that the component that is parallel to the surface is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Lagrange's method, you do search for points with gradient zero, but this is done for Lagrange function not the given one! I think the difference between Lagrange and derivative methods is best understood by doing a single example using both methods. The Calculus book written by Stewart edition 6th, examples 14.7.6 p.928 and 14.8.1 p.936, contains such an example done in both methods. Please write down the solutions in both methods on a sheet of paper in separate columns and compare the methods. Here are some points that might help:

//

1- In derivative method we need an explicit formula of the given function with specified dependent and independent variables. In contrast, in applying Lagrange's method you don't need to decide which variable is dependent or independent in advance, and this is a big advantage.
//

2- If you want to apply Lagrange's method for a function like z=f(x,y), you need to go one dimension higher and form the new function F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z. I think you confused grad(f) with grad(F), and that was the source of your confusion-grad(F) is obviously non-zero. In derivative method you search for points where grad(f)=0, but in Lagrange's, you first make Lagrange function L, which is a combination of F and the constraint, and then search for points where grad(L)=0.

//

3-The derivative method works for solid regions in the domain of the original function, while in the Lagrange method you work with the shell of certain shapes which are level sets of a function from one dimension higher.

//

I hope these explanations help.

Answer (score 0):

So if the gradient were zero on the constraint surface, that would be fine (and it would satisfy the Lagrange condition). But typically this doesn't happen; for instance, if you're extremizing $f(x,y)=x+y$, its gradient is never $0$, but this function still has extrema on the unit circle.

The key fact here is that if $S$ is the surface $\{ \mathbf{x} : g(\mathbf{x})=0 \}$, the tangent (hyper)plane of $S$ at each point is perpendicular to the gradient of $g$ at that point. This means that the Lagrange condition can be understood as "the gradient of $f$ is perpendicular to the tangent (hyper)plane of $S$". So the Lagrange condition tells you that if you move in a direction tangent to $S$, $f$ will not change to first order. If it did, then you could go a sufficiently short distance in one direction to increase $f$, and a sufficiently short distance in the opposite direction to decrease $f$. Finally, it turns out that what we've said about the tangent directions transfers to the surface itself.

Thus the Lagrange condition is necessary (under the "regularity" hypotheses of the Lagrange multiplier theorem, which include the constraint qualification--see comments). Just like in the unconstrained case, it is not sufficient.

Comment: Necessary if the maximizer/minimizer satisfies the constraint qualification

Comment: @smcc Yes there are hypotheses to be stated, the asker can check a standard reference for these if they are confused about them. Note that technically any unconstrained problem can be viewed as a constrained problem; one can rewrite "extremize $f$" as "extremize $f$ subject to $g=0$ where $g \equiv 0$". Thus "the problem is constrained" is not really a hypothesis in the Lagrange multiplier theorem; one can always introduce a vacuous constraint, and doing so recovers the more familiar unconstrained first order condition.

Comment: I was just pointing that out a maximizer/minimizer which does not satisfy the constraint qualification will not necessarily be a critical point of the Lagrangian. I am not sure that any of your comment after the first sentence is relevant to the point I was making.

Comment: @smcc What do you mean? Are you just saying that a maximizer which isn't on the constraint surface won't necessarily satisfy the Lagrange condition? That seems rather obvious and unimportant (why would you check the Lagrange condition in an unconstrained problem?)

Comment: Do you not know about the constraint qualification? Maybe you should look it up.To see why it is important consider the problem $\min_{x,y} x^2+y^2$ subject to $g(x,y)=(x-1)^3-y^2=0$. There is no critical point of the Lagrangian for this problem, yet a solution exists (the minimizer is $(1,0)$). The problem does not satisfy the constraint qualification because at the minimizer, $g_x=g_y=0$.

Comment: Now I see your point. I hadn't heard the term before, and expected it to be a non-technical term. Thanks for the comment, I will revise.

Comment: So what you said in the answer is equivalent to that the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the tangent to the plane of S, must be 0(means that the function doesn't change in any direction), and because $D_vf=<\nabla f,v>=0$, then $f$ must be perpendicular to v, but also g is. So we look for gradient of f equals 0 only in a nice, open set, not necessarily in constraint optimization? Because I have the problem with the statement: if A is an extreme point, THEN the gradient is 0.

Comment: @Mr.Tea Yes, you shouldn't expect the gradient of the objective function to vanish at extreme points in constrained problems.

Answer (score 0):

Searching only for vanishing gradients you typically miss the constraint extrema.

Suppose the constraints are given by $S=\{x: g_1(x)=c_1,...,g_k(x)=0\}$.  Take any $C^1$ curve $x(t)$ satisfying the constraints and with $x(0)=a$. Then for all $i$:
$$ 0 = \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} g_i(x(t))= \nabla g_i (a) \cdot x'(0)$$

Now, if  $f(x)$ has an extremum at $a$ subject to these constraints
then we must also have
$$ 0 = \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} f(x(t))= \nabla f (a) \cdot x'(0)$$
This is clearly ok if $\nabla f(a)=\lambda_1 \nabla g_1(a) +\cdots + \lambda_k \nabla g_k(a)$, i.e. is a linear combination of the $\nabla g_i(a)$'s. It is now a theorem of linear algebra that this is the only possibility. The theorem is that if $W$ is a subspace (here the span of the $\nabla g_i(a)$'s) and $u \perp W^\perp$ then $u\in W$.

Answer (score 0):

In this post, I am only going to work with 2 variables, but this can be generalized to $n$ variables.

Maximize $f(x,y)$ when constrained to $g(x,y)=0$.

We can express $g(x,y)$ as a parametric equation, say $(X(t), Y(t))$.

Say that $(x_0, y_0)$ is an extremum of $f(x,y)$ along the curve $g(x,y)=0$. We can find a value $t_0$ such that $X(t_0)=x_0$ and $Y(t_0)=y_0$. Then, the point $t_0$ must be an extremum for the function $f(X(t),Y(t))$. In other words: $$\frac{df(X(t),Y(t))}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial X(t)}\bigg|_{t=t_0}\cdot\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0}+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial Y(t)}\bigg|_{t=t_0}\cdot\frac{dY(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0}=0$$

This means that $\displaystyle\nabla f(X(t_0),Y(t_0))\cdot\left(\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0},\frac{dY(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0}\right)=0$.

In other words, the vector $\nabla f(X(t_0),Y(t_0))$ is perpendicular to $\displaystyle\left(\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0},\frac{dY(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0}\right)$.

To add on, we know that, while $\displaystyle\left(\frac{dX(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0},\frac{dY(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=t_0}\right)$ is a tangent vector to the curve $g(x,y)=0$, the vector $\nabla g(X(t_0),Y(t_0))$  is a normal vector (since $g(x,y)=0$ is a contour). Ergo, we conclude that these vectors are also perpendicular.

This means that $\nabla f(X(t_0),Y(t_0))=\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ and $\nabla g(X(t_0),Y(t_0))=\nabla g(x_0,y_0)$ must be parallel. In other words $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=\lambda \nabla g(x_0,y_0)$.